# Why can't singleton methods be defined on Symbols or Fixnums?

Tags: ruby

There are a some Ruby classes that don't allow singleton methods to be defined on their instances. For example, `Symbol`:

```
var = :asymbol

def var.hello
  "hello"
end

# TypeError: can't define singleton method "hello" for Symbol
```

*I thought this might be a restriction on all immediate values, but it seems to work for `nil`, `true`, and `false`* (but not instances of `Fixnum` or `Bignum`):

```
var = true

def var.hello
  "hello"
end

var.hello #=> "hello"
```

I don't understand why why Ruby allows singleton methods to be defined on certain classes of objects but not others.

Comment: It seems to not just be `Fixnum`s, but any `Numeric`.

Comment: My gut reaction is that it has something to do w/ types that would be the same value regardless of context. A symbol `:fred` will always be the same symbol object, as will `5`. Unfortunately, the same is true for `true`, so it's something deeper than that; I'd wonder first if it's the same across versions, then wonder how each type's constancy was implemented.

Comment: The doc for [Object#singleton_class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-singleton_class) states, "If [receiver] `obj` is `nil`, `true`, or `false` it returns `NilClass`, `TrueClass` or `FalseClass`, respectively. If `obj` is a `Fixnum` or a `Symbol`, it raises a `TypeError`." As @Andrew notes, however, no numeric value can have a singleton class. `nil`, `true` and `false` have singleton classes (e.g., `class << false; puts self; end #=> FalseClass`), but since those classes have only a single instance, there's no point to distinguish between the class and the singleton class.

Comment: I suspect `nil` has a singleton class for the same reason that it has instance methods `to_a`, `to_c`, `to_f`, `to_h`, `to_i`, `to_r` and `to_s`; namely, it allows for a soft landing when, for example, the receiver of `singleton_class` could be either `nil` or something else. That logic does not extend to `true` and `false`, however.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This has to do with a concept called 'immediate values' as described [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=jcUbTcr5XWwC&pg=PA73&lpg=PA73&dq=immediate%20values%20singleton%20method&source=bl&ots=fIFlAe8xjy&sig=j7WgTA1Cft0WrHwq40YdTA50wk0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0kHSUKCVB-bW0gHRxoHQAg&ved=0CD8Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Matz.

In truth, no immediate values should permit a singleton method.  However, in the case of `true`, `false`, and `nil`, there are actually singleton classes that back these values (or the value is actually the singleton class - I'm not sure about this).  You can therefore add singleton instances to the backing class which manifests as though it were the value itself.  Numeric and Symbol instances are not singletons (obviously) and have nowhere to hold singleton methods.

Comment: Hmm, are `true`, `false`, and `nil` really no longer immediate values? Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: It appears that they [are indeed still immediate values](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ObjectSpace.html#each_object-method).  The actual difference is described above, see updated.

Comment: It's not clear why immediate values should not permit singleton methods. It's not like adding a method mutates the value. Some integers, floats and symbols are stored as objects (non-immediate values). And as such could potentially have singleton methods. The values of `true`, `false`, `nil` are not actually the singleton classes. Add singleton methods, not instances to the backing class? See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75633801/52499).

Comment: @x-yuri at the end of your answer: "If you were able to add singleton methods to integers, floats and symbols, then ruby would be forced to store them as objects (those with extra methods). Which eliminates the optimization."  Which was exactly my point.  Immediate values that don't have a backing singleton class have nowhere to store the method without losing the implementation as an immediate value.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment (`ruby-3.2.1`) you can't define singleton methods for integers, floats, symbols and frozen strings (I also confirmed it with `ruby-2.6.10`):

```
v = Object.new
v = nil
v = false
v = true
v = 'string'
v = 1                       #=> TypeError: can't define singleton
v = 1000000000000000000000  #=> TypeError: can't define singleton
v = 1.0                     #=> TypeError: can't define singleton
v = 1e100                   #=> TypeError: can't define singleton
v = :sym                    #=> TypeError: can't define singleton
v = :"sym#{v}"              #=> TypeError: can't define singleton
v = -'string'               #=> TypeError: can't define singleton
def v.m() end
```

And the corresponding part of the code is [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v3_2_1/class.c#L2134-L2153):

```
static VALUE
singleton_class_of(VALUE obj)
{
    VALUE klass;

    switch (TYPE(obj)) {
      case T_FIXNUM:
      case T_BIGNUM:
      case T_FLOAT:
      case T_SYMBOL:
        rb_raise(rb_eTypeError, "can't define singleton");

      case T_FALSE:
      case T_TRUE:
      case T_NIL:
        klass = special_singleton_class_of(obj);
        if (NIL_P(klass))
            rb_bug("unknown immediate %p", (void *)obj);
        return klass;

      case T_STRING:
        if (FL_TEST_RAW(obj, RSTRING_FSTR)) {
            rb_raise(rb_eTypeError, "can't define singleton");
        }
    }
    ...
```

Now, let's look at what [`TYPE`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v3_2_1/include/ruby/internal/value_type.h#L107) does:

```
#define TYPE(_)           RBIMPL_CAST((int)rb_type(_))
```

[`rb_type()`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v3_2_1/include/ruby/internal/value_type.h#L223-L251):

```
static inline enum ruby_value_type
rb_type(VALUE obj)
{
    if (! RB_SPECIAL_CONST_P(obj)) {
        return RB_BUILTIN_TYPE(obj);
    }
    else if (obj == RUBY_Qfalse) {
        return RUBY_T_FALSE;
    }
    else if (obj == RUBY_Qnil) {
        return RUBY_T_NIL;
    }
    else if (obj == RUBY_Qtrue) {
        return RUBY_T_TRUE;
    }
    else if (obj == RUBY_Qundef) {
        return RUBY_T_UNDEF;
    }
    else if (RB_FIXNUM_P(obj)) {
        return RUBY_T_FIXNUM;
    }
    else if (RB_STATIC_SYM_P(obj)) {
        return RUBY_T_SYMBOL;
    }
    else {
        RBIMPL_ASSUME(RB_FLONUM_P(obj));
        return RUBY_T_FLOAT;
    }
}
```

That's a lot of information. Let me give you [some constants](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v3_2_1/include/ruby/internal/special_consts.h#L98-L106) first:

```
    RUBY_Qfalse         = 0x00, /* ...0000 0000 */
    RUBY_Qnil           = 0x04, /* ...0000 0100 */
    RUBY_Qtrue          = 0x14, /* ...0001 0100 */
    RUBY_Qundef         = 0x24, /* ...0010 0100 */
    RUBY_IMMEDIATE_MASK = 0x07, /* ...0000 0111 */
    RUBY_FIXNUM_FLAG    = 0x01, /* ...xxxx xxx1 */
    RUBY_FLONUM_MASK    = 0x03, /* ...0000 0011 */
    RUBY_FLONUM_FLAG    = 0x02, /* ...xxxx xx10 */
    RUBY_SYMBOL_FLAG    = 0x0c, /* ...xxxx 1100 */
```

and some [type constants](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v3_2_1/include/ruby/internal/value_type.h#L110-L145):

```
    RUBY_T_FLOAT    = 0x04, /**< @see struct ::RFloat */
    RUBY_T_STRING   = 0x05, /**< @see struct ::RString */
    RUBY_T_BIGNUM   = 0x0a, /**< @see struct ::RBignum */
    RUBY_T_NIL      = 0x11, /**< @see ::RUBY_Qnil */
    RUBY_T_TRUE     = 0x12, /**< @see ::RUBY_Qfalse */
    RUBY_T_FALSE    = 0x13, /**< @see ::RUBY_Qtrue */
    RUBY_T_SYMBOL   = 0x14, /**< @see struct ::RSymbol */
    RUBY_T_FIXNUM   = 0x15, /**< Integers formerly known as Fixnums. */
```

So, what are immediate values?

[`RB_IMMEDIATE_P`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v3_2_1/include/ruby/internal/special_consts.h#L310-L314):

```
static inline bool
RB_IMMEDIATE_P(VALUE obj)
{
    return obj & RUBY_IMMEDIATE_MASK;
}
```

[`RB_SPECIAL_CONST_P`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v3_2_1/include/ruby/internal/special_consts.h#L326-L330):

```
static inline bool
RB_SPECIAL_CONST_P(VALUE obj)
{
    return RB_IMMEDIATE_P(obj) || obj == RUBY_Qfalse;
}
```

The names in the code seems a bit misleading, but the following way it more or less makes sense. Immediate values are values that have any of the 3 least significant bits set and `RUBY_Qfalse`. Some of the immediate values are constants, like `nil` (`0x04`), `false` (`0x00`), `true` (`0x14`). Some simply store the values inline (or at least don't point somewhere), like fixnums (integers), flonums (floats) and static symbols.

[`RB_FIXNUM_P`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v3_2_1/include/ruby/internal/special_consts.h#L246-L250) (is a fixnum?):

```
static inline bool
RB_FIXNUM_P(VALUE obj)
{
    return obj & RUBY_FIXNUM_FLAG;
}
```

[`RB_FLONUM_P`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v3_2_1/include/ruby/internal/special_consts.h#L287-L295) (is a flonum?):

```
static inline bool
RB_FLONUM_P(VALUE obj)
{
#if USE_FLONUM
    return (obj & RUBY_FLONUM_MASK) == RUBY_FLONUM_FLAG;
#else
    return false;
#endif
}
```

[`RB_STATIC_SYM_P`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v3_2_1/include/ruby/internal/special_consts.h#L266-L272) (is a static symbol?):

```
static inline bool
RB_STATIC_SYM_P(VALUE obj)
{
    RBIMPL_ATTR_CONSTEXPR(CXX14)
    const VALUE mask = ~(RBIMPL_VALUE_FULL << RUBY_SPECIAL_SHIFT);
    return (obj & mask) == RUBY_SYMBOL_FLAG;
}
```

[`RB_BUILTIN_TYPE`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v3_2_1/include/ruby/internal/value_type.h#L180-L192) (returns the type of a non-immediate value, of a value that the pointer points to):

```
static inline enum ruby_value_type
RB_BUILTIN_TYPE(VALUE obj)
{
    ...
    VALUE ret = RBASIC(obj)->flags & RUBY_T_MASK;
    return RBIMPL_CAST((enum ruby_value_type)ret);
}
```

[`RBASIC`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v3_2_1/include/ruby/internal/core/rbasic.h#L40) (typecast to `struct RBasic*`, that's a struct that conforms to any `VALUE`, that's not a pointer):

```
#define RBASIC(obj)                 RBIMPL_CAST((struct RBasic *)(obj))
```

And `FL_TEST_RAW(obj, RSTRING_FSTR)`? That's a way to check if a string is frozen.

Now, actually some integers, floats and symbols are stored as pointers. That's why I have 2 checks per each of these types: `1` (immediate) and `1000000000000000000000` (pointer), `1.0` (immediate) and `1e100` (pointer), `:sym` (immediate) and `:"sym#{v}"` (pointer, dynamic symbol). In `ruby-2.6` the distinction is [more apparent](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_6_10/class.c#L1600-L1618).

As for why you can add methods to `nil`, but not to integers? Beats me :) Most likely because `nil` is one, and integers are many. At the moment it's up to `ruby` to choose whether to store a value inline or in an object. If you were able to add singleton methods to integers, floats and symbols, then `ruby` would be forced to store them as objects (those with extra methods). Which eliminates the optimization. And was probably considered as doing more harm than good.

And `-'string'` [is a](https://ruby-doc.com/core/String.html#method-i-2D-40) frozen string, by the way.