# how to define singleton method within a ruby method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4.1, ruby-2.1

In ruby 1.9, one could do this:

```
def foo
  val = "a string"
  def val.big
    self.upcase
  end
  val
end
```

and one could call foo, with "a string" returned, or foo.big and get "A STRING" returned.

However this is no longer possible in Ruby 2.1, an error "cannot define singleton method" is thrown. How would the methods be implemented in 2.1 for foo and foo.big?

(Obviously this is a simplified example, what I need to do is implement a singleton method on the value returned by another method).

UPDATE: it appears that this IS possible in ruby 2.1, but NOT in the context of an ActiveRecord class!

SECOND UPDATE: When val is a string, this does work. My the problem surfaces when one tries to define a singleton class on a number like this:

```
def foo
  val = 42
  def val.smaller
     self - 11
  end
  val
end
```

this throws the error "TypeError: can't define singleton"

Comment: I wonder if your problem is elsewhere? The example above works fine on both `ruby 2.1.7p400` and `ruby 2.2.3p173`  from the quick testing with rubies I had on hand here..

Comment: yes, thanks Doon, I noticed the same thing myself after posting this. Looks as if ActiveRecord is borking the singleton method definition.

Comment: So `val` is an ActiveRecord Instance? IF so what is it exactly?(What class)

Comment: look here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962147/why-cant-singleton-methods-be-defined-on-symbols-or-fixnums  has to to with immediate values.

Comment: that's it, yes, thanks Doon.