# Why can't I define methods on numbers?

Tags: ruby, singleton

In Ruby, I can define methods just on an object:

```
x = "asht"

def x.roman
  "works!"
end
x.roman # => "works"

"asht".roman # => NoMethodError: undefined method `roman' for "asht":String
```

However, this doesn't work for numbers

```
def 0.roman
  "doesn't work :'("
end # => SyntaxError: (irb):5: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER

x = 0
def x.roman
  "doesn't work :'("
end # => TypeError: can't define singleton
```

Why?

Comment: This might answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962147/why-cant-singleton-methods-be-defined-on-symbols-or-fixnums

Comment: Thanks, it does. I think the question can be closed as a duplicate.