# Why fixnum doesn't have eigenclass?

Tags: ruby, eigenclass

This method is to return eigenclass of any object:

```
class Object
  def eigenclass
    class << self; self; end
  end
end
```

Example for String:

```
"abc".eigenclass # => #<Class:#<String:0x331df0>>
```

Array:

```
[1, 2].eigenclass # => #<Class:#<Array:0x0000000065d218>>
```

But with Fixnum:

```
1.eigenclass # => TypeError: can't define singleton
```

Why?

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962147/why-cant-singleton-methods-be-defined-on-symbols-or-fixnums) might help you. Please go through it.

Answer (score 1):

As the [Ruby Docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Fixnum.html) say:

> There is effectively only one Fixnum object instance for any given integer value, so, for example, you cannot add a singleton method to a Fixnum.

The same is true for `Bignum`, `Float` and `Symbol`